# How can I use wildcards in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, wildcard

I have a switch statement that uses a string of 3 letters. For many cases (but not all) I only want to concern myself with the first 2 letters.

Example, I want every code that begins with "FF" to be handled the same:

```
switch(code)
{
   case "FF(?)":
      // Handle it
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

What can I do here? Can I utilize a wildcard? Do I have to consider every FF code?

For obvious reasons, I don't want to have code like this, that can grow really large:

```
case "FFA":
case "FFB":
case "FFD":
    // Handle it
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do your first 2 chars at the `switch`, not at `case`.

Use the `default` case to then fall back to three letter cases.  It's not the cleanest, but it would work.  Sometimes `if` statements are the way to go if switches don't cut it.

```
switch(code.Substring(0, 2))
{
    case "FF":
       ...
    default:
        switch(code)
        {
            case "ABC":
                ....
        }
}
```

Comment: But sometimes I will need to handle all 3 letters.

Comment: This doesn't handle some of the cases - he mentioned "(but not all)" in the text...

Comment: @McAdam331 Then parse `code` into another var that gives you the prefix and switch on that var.  (Nathan, i think you went from decent to much worse with that edit.)

Comment: @paqogomez +1 Hence the reason I added my blurb about falling back to using `if`.

Comment: I don't think the edit is bad at all. In fact, it makes a lot of sense. In most cases, I will handle 2 chars, but sometimes I want to know all 3 and this works. The If/Else answers also make sense, but I personally feel switch statements are easier to read.

Comment: Would there be any differences in efficiency between using the above switch statement, as opposed to if/else?

Comment: Couldn't say for your case, as it varies: http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-switch-performance

Comment: Good read, thanks. I'll definitely take this answer. I've been able to sit back and realize that in the vast majority of cases I won't be concerned with this 3rd letter, so I will save it for a default block, or a ternary operator like @CharlesBretana answered.

Answer (score 5):

Use `if then else` for these kinds of comparisons.  Reserve your `switch` `case` statements for cases that are readily identifiable as discrete values.

Comment: Although nothing prevents non-discrete values (not that you implied so), it certainly is more legible, maintainable, and understandable when they are discrete.

Answer (score 3):

just use a ternary operator in the switch statement

```
 switch (code.StartsWith("FF")? code.substring(0,2): code)
 {
     case "FF":

     case "FAS":

     case "FAY"

     // etc.
 }
```

for multiples, do this:

```
 switch (new[] {"FF", "GG", "HH", "JJ"}.Contains(code.substring(0,2))?
                    code.substring(0,2): code)
 {
     case "FF":
     case "GG":
     case "HH":
     case "JJ":

     case "FAS":

     case "FAY"

     // etc.
 }
```

Comment: That would work if the only two letter check was for "FF", but it would get rather ugly if you wanted to check for multiple 2-letter cases.

Comment: Yes, but I posit still cleaner than multiple nested If Else if statements

Comment: I like this a lot too. I think I could do the opposite, since 3 letter cases are going to be more rare. I could say `switch(code.Equals("ABC") ? code : code.substring(0,2)` and it wouldn't be horribly cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome suggestions guys, I really appreciate it. I'm definitely going to keep both in mind moving forward, because I'm sure this won't be the last time I come across this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

The Switch statement in C# doesn't support this.  You would need to use if/else statements instead:

```
if (code.StartsWith("FF"))
{
    // Handle it
}
else if (code == "HFD") // etc
{
    // Handle it
}
else 
{
    // default case
}
```